VUE can not display Chinese
I want to show Chinese in VUE, so I set utf-8 in index.html

However, when I finish coding and enter "npm run dev" to run this web app

there is still messy string on browser

Why does utf-8 not work? How to let VUE show Chinese? Any suggestion to me?

Please, provide a way to reproduce. Meta charset and correct source encoding are enough, generally it's as simple as that

Check the visual-studio encoding format ,it may not be utf-8.

You maybe haven't declared it correctly in the app.vue file
it should look something like this
metaInfo() {
  return {
    title: 'My',
    titleTemplate: '%s | Titulo',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { equiv: 'Content-Type', content: 'text/html' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' }
    ]
  }
}

